# Ruby equivalent of lisp-like "apply"?

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I would like to create an instance method that takes another instance method of its own class as a parameter, and then applies the passed method on the instance it's working on (known as `self`):

```
class MyClass

  attr_reader :called_methods

  def initialize
    @called_methods = []
  end

  def my_first_method!
    @called_methods << :my_first_method
    self
  end

  def my_second_method!
    @called_methods << :my_second_method
    self
  end

  def my_strange_method!(secondary)
    # Want to apply method whose name is given by secondary, to self
  end
end

p MyClass.new.my_second_method!.my_strange_method!(:my_first_method!).called_methods
```

I suspect the unary `&` may be key, but all the web pages I can find on that operator involve calling methods on multiple objects, as when iterating over an `Enumerable` with `#each` or `#map`.

Comment: Ah, thanks much. So for my comment line, `self.public_send(secondary)`. It gives the result I wanted. Why specify public? Security reasons?

Comment: By using `public_send` you clearly show the intent. Also it will fail on attempt to call protected/private method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object#public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-public_send) (or [`Object#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) to apply protected/private method).

```
def my_strange_method!(secondary)
  public_send(secondary)
  self
end

p MyClass.new.
    my_second_method!.
    my_strange_method!(:my_first_method!).
    called_methods
#⇒ [:my_second_method, :my_first_method]
```

---

There could be more defensive way to apply if and only the method is known:

```
def my_strange_method!(secondary)
  raise ArgumentError.new("Unknown method #{secondary}") \
    unless methods.include? secondary.to_s.to_sym
  public_send(secondary)
end

p MyClass.new.
    my_second_method!.
    my_strange_method!(:my_first_method!).
    called_methods
#⇒ [:my_second_method, :my_first_method]

p MyClass.new.
    my_second_method!.
    my_strange_method!(:inexisting_method!).
    called_methods
#⇒ ArgumentError: Unknown method inexisting_method!
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tagged with *functional-programming* so I'm going to offer a persistent (immutable) design -

```
class MyClass

  attr_reader :called_methods

  def initialize(m = [])
    @called_methods = m
  end

  def my_first_method!
    MyClass.new(called_methods + [ :first ])
  end

  def my_second_method!
    MyClass.new(called_methods + [ :second ])
  end

  def my_strange_method!(secondary)
    public_send secondary
  end
end

MyClass.new.my_second_method!.my_strange_method!(:my_first_method!).called_methods
# [:second, :first]
```

Comment: Spaces between the method name and opening parenthesis are an anti-pattern in ruby and might lead to weird hard-to-find bugs under some circumstances. Also, I doubt I understand why creating a dozillion of new classes makes any sense here.

Comment: Clearly I shouldn't have included the `functional-programming` tag. Clearly in functional programming there are no ! methods. Oops.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I fixed the spaces. Ruby highly favors object-oriented pattern where mutation and side effects are the norm, however the language makes functional style possible. Persistent data structures are a cornerstone of the functional pattern and the question is answered in this context.